# Keyboard does not respond on normal pressure - Key stroke sensitivity is very low

Tags: keyboard, dconf, user-profile

Today my keyboard started responding weird while I was writing in an editor. First there was no problem, but after a while the keyboard did only respond on very hard key strokes. I have to push a key with pressure until the very end and only then I can trigger an key stroke event.

I did not change any configuration nor did I change my hardware setup.* Maybe I have pressed an uncommon shortcut combination. I also noticed that this only affects my user. When I am logged out or on another user account then there is no problem. Thus I exclude any hardware problem.

**In which user configuration file/folder can I find the potential troublemaker for the keyboard? Is there maybe a threshold I could change?**

Where I looked for it yet:

- `.bashrc` which is working fine under another user account.
- `.dbus` which I renamed an then logged in, but the problem was still there.
- `.local` which I renamed an then logged in, but the problem was still there.
- [20:00] **Yet I know, it must be somewhere in `.config`**, because when I renamed it to `.config.bkp` an logged in all was fine.
- [20:22] its not in `.config/ibus/`
- [20:26] **it is somewhere in `.config/dconf/`**

---

**Now you probably think (and you should), that of course I must have changed something to make this happen, but it wasn't me as far as I can remember. I just was programming with the [atom](https://atom.io/) editor and the fancy programming language [julia](http://julialang.org/) - plotting charts with "Plots" and not "Gadfly" - sorry Gadfly team, but Plots has the better syntax.*

Comment: Is this a USB keyboard, builtin keyboard, etc.?

Comment: It affects both... the onboard laptop keyboard and my USB/Wireless keyboard.

Comment: You might want to see this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1091041. I've never heard of keyboard sensitivities fluctuating based on the programs being run, and gradually fluctuating, as well.

Comment: Hmm... `xset r rate 500 30` did not work (and some variations). But there is no problem with the repetitiveness, which works normal. Once a button is pushed down it starts to repeat normally. It just takes a lot of pressure until it starts and I would have to hold it down.